# how can i remove padding on small screen when i need padding on desktop screen in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

```css
.nir{
padding-top:170px;
padding-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 nir col-md-offset-1 col-xs-offset-2 ">
 
      <img src="Kiara.png"  class="img-rounded " alt="Cinque Terre">
   
 </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-offset-1">
      <img src="divyam.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="onourown.png" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my code where I apply css 'class nir' on a div to get top padding in desktop, but i don't want padding in small screen(mobile). So how can i do this Please suggest me.(I don't want to use media screen)

Comment: you can only do it with media query.

Answer (score 1):

you can use @media in your .css file for example in your css file add something like this

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
    .nir{
           padding-top:0px;
           padding-left:0px;
    }
}
```

change max width to whatever screen size you desire, in this example anything less than 600px will have 0 padding